# Maven plugin for copying and modifying file

Tags: regex, maven

In my project there are 2 files in resources. Both are almost same except the second one contains additions to the content of the first one at some places.

When I need to modify something in these files I often end up editing both which is very bad practice which I decided to change.

How can I achieve this in Maven build? I imagine a plugin which would make copy of the first file and at some place in the document denoted by regex or something similar it will put the additional content which would be stored in a help file.

Answer (score 0):

use maven-antrun plugin. You can do several custom operations during your build.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
       <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>copy-swf-files</id>
             <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <target name="copy swf files to web project">
                       <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.swf" tofile="${swf.output.location}/foo.swf" />
                       <copy file="${project.build.directory}/a.swf" tofile="${swf.output.location}/a.swf" />
                       <copy file="${project.build.directory}/z.swf" tofile="${swf.output.location}/z.swf" />
                    </target>
                 </configuration>                       
              </execution>
           </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, may be maven [filter functionality](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) can be used in your system?
You can define different filters for different profile and define multi-line variable inside. During filtering your resources you got token replacement within values from filter